# update multipe values of checkbox in the column, codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

The view, the controller and the model are below. post submit the page returns to the page type and no value is saved in the database. Now I am not sure what details should I type please ignore this further because its all nonsense. I have to type it for the more details but I don't have anymore.
view

```html
<form action="<?=  base_url()?>user/type" method="post">
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Textile" name="type[]">Textile</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Jewellery" name="type[]"></label>Jewellery</div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Footwear" name="type[]">Footwear</label></div>
</form>
```

controller

```html
  function type()
  {
  if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
        {
           $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
          $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
   $data['title'] = 'Type';

   $type=$this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'required');


   if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
             $data['main_view']="users/v_type";
  $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
  $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar',$data);
  $this->load->view('layouts/footer',$data);
   } else {
    // Encrypt password
   
    $this->m_user->type(); //m_user is model

    // Set message
   
          if($data['user']->profile_pic==null)
          {
                redirect(base_url().'user/profilepicture/');
          }
   else
    {
         redirect(base_url().'user/');
    }
    }
}
}
```

Model

```html
          public function type(){
           $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
          $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
        $type = $this->input->post('type');
        $data=array('type'=>json_encode(implode(",", $type)),);
   $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
   return $this->db->update('users', $data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your checkboxes dont have any values set. You can always check which variables you send via POST to your controller by typing:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($this->input->post());
echo '</pre><br><br>';
```

an example for checkbox with value would be

```
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Footwear" name="type[]">Footwear</label></div>
```

in your case

Comment: I forgot to add values on stackoverflow, but the actual form has the value and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not getting checkbox value in the controller like this `$this->input->post()`

Second, don't get form value in the model. You should learn how MVC works

**Controller**

```
 function type(){
if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
{
    $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
    $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('type[]', 'Type', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $data['main_view']="users/v_type";
        $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar',$data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer',$data);
    } else {
        // Encrypt password

        $type = $this->input->post('type');
        $this->m_user->type($type); //m_user is model

        // Set message
    }
    if($data['user']->profile_pic==null){
        redirect(base_url().'user/profilepicture/');
    }else{
        redirect(base_url().'user/');
    }
}
}
```

**Model**

```
public function type($type){
  $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
  $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
  $data=array('type'=>json_encode(implode(",", $type)));
  $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
  return $this->db->update('users', $data);
}
```

Checkbox validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('type[]', 'Type', 'required');
```

Comment: on clicking submit the page again lands upon the type page without submitting the data in the database.

Comment: use this to check validation error message if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){ validation_errors();}

Comment: @Naren means you are not getting value from view to controller. Before if($this->session->userdata("user_id")) try this print_r($this->input->post())

Comment: Array ( [type] => Array ( [0] => Textile ) [add] => Submit & Next )

Comment: what is the result of this line in the model? $data=array('type'=>json_encode(implode(",", $type)));

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
Sorry but this all I have for the explanation.